# Can't crop JPEG with GIMP 2.8.16 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, gimp

I have used GIMP for a long time to crop photos. Recently, I have not been able to do this. If I perform the usual procedure (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, etc.), the file is not cropped. Restarting the program and/or the OS does not help.

I have version 2.8.16 installed on 64-bit Ubuntu (`4.4.0-138-generic #164-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 2 17:16:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`). Plenty of memory (32GB), processor AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor × 8, graphics GeForce GT 630/PCIe/SSE2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it works fine for me on bionic with Gimp 2.8.22. There are other options though to crop images, I prefer to crop JPEGs losslessly with https://github.com/jepler/cropgui

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem on the .jpg file? (my go-to suspicion for strange Ubuntu problems is file permissions/owners)

Comment: I  now wonder  whether the problem might have to do with the JPEG file itself, rather than with GIMP. The JPEG files with which I had this problem were produced by scanning SW. I  tried to crop some other JPEGs that were created by a digital camera, and the crop feature works in the way to which I was accustomed . So the problem might have something to do with the JPEG file format produced by the scanning SW. I am still curious to know what is going on, but I think that the problem is not necessarily with GIMP. I will soon post the information about the scanner and scanning SW.

Comment: The software was: ControlCenter 4 for Windows 7, which is provided with the scanner (also printer and copy machine) Brother DCP-7065DN. I will do some more tests. However, I seem to recall that if I scan to a bitmap (BMP) file (also on Windows), GIMP on Ubuntu can crop it. I suspect that this Windows SW is producing a JPEG that GIMP on Ubuntu has trouble dealing with.

Comment: May be the file was created using an indexed color profile or something like that. I havn't had this with JPEGs but I recall that there was something similar going on when I used indexd PNGs. From the menu bar go to Image → Mode and check if it says Indexed…, then change to Grayscale or RGB. exiftool output might help identifying where the produced image file differs from usual JPEGs.

Comment: If the file loads in Gimp then it's not a problem of input file format. Does the image appears cropped in Gimp? Not clear if the problem is Crop tool problem or a file save problem.

Comment: When I first open the file with GIMP, I can see the image just as I expect it, with the extra area around what I want to save. I activate the crop tool (I've tried it in different ways: Shift-C, etc.), & I can draw a rectangle around the area I want to save. Already then -- before I click in the desired area that I want to save -- the surrounding area to be cropped disappears. But if I then click in the area I want to save, the area I wanted to disappear REAPPEARS. I've tried saving the file before & after clicking in the "good" area, but it doesn't matter. The file is not cropped.